# Join SQL results in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need an SQL query that merge some results, but they have to match...

For example, see this image :
[image: Image of the tables]

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN. And use coalesce on BuyPrice.

Comment: What you have tried. And why is buyPrice in the last record 10.6?

Comment: Thanks... BuyPrice in last record is 10.6 because its just a sample and i didnt notice that it was higher than AVGPrice.. it should be 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.product, t1.quantity, t1.avgprice, coalesce(t2.buyprice, 0)
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.product = t2.product
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is there to also return table1 rows without a matching table2 row.

`coalesce(t2.buyprice, 0)` is used to return 0 if no t2.buyprice (i.e. t2.buyprice is null).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a query with JOIN statement.

```
SELECT t1.Product, t1.Quantity, t1.AVGPrice, t2.BuyPrice
FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Product = t2.Product
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join, like this:

```
SELECT t1.product, t1.quantity, t1.avgprice, ISNULL(t2.buyprice, 0)
FROM table1 t1
   LEFT JOIN table2 t2
      ON t1.product = t2.product
```